# Can I self-sign my non-production kernel driver to run on my particular system?

Tags: windows-10, kernel, code-signing, self-signed, ca

I know that Windows kernel drivers have to be signed with an EV certificate to run on a 64-bit version of Windows 10. I also know that I can disable driver signing on my test system by running this command:

```
Bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

My goal is to write a non-production driver for my own system. It will not be installed anywhere else. I don't want to disable driver signing for the entire system, I just want to enable my particular driver to run on this particular system.

I am basically trying to see if I can create a self-signed certificate, add it to the root store and sign my driver with it. (Again, in a non-production environment.)

Can I do this? And if so, then how?